# Using Grid Layout with Parallax

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am trying to create a grid layout in conjunction with parallax. I have a div element (in Parallax below) which has a grid layout defined in CSS, containing three sub div elements. The second div has a background style applied to it, but the style is being applied across all divs.

I am basically trying to have a white box displayed in the middle of the page, which scrolls with the help of parallax, while currently I have a white stripe displayed across the entire page.

Is this feasible?

```css
.parallax {
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.inParallax {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax"></div>
<div class="inParallax">
   <div></div>
   <div style="height:200px;background-color:white;">
   <p>Text</p>
   </div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add additional content to produce a [mcve] of your issue. You can use additional filler text or sample photos hosted online (or upload them here) if you are hesitant to put your actual content on the site, but we need to see a reproducible example of your current code to understand what your issue is and how to solve it.

Comment: An image reference would help what you're trying to achieve. Make sure the `background-image` property value points to a valid image url